# class objects does not get saved in parse databrowser android

Tags: java, android, object, arraylist, parse-platform

I have started with parse to store the data of my class. I have followed parse guide and tutorials and tried to implement the code. Unfortunately, the objects of class are not getting saved in parse data browser. When I see the data in browser just one object id is shown not the columns of name, desc and qty of my item class. I have created class in dashboard also created columns respective to my data. Unable to get the solution as I am new to android and parse.

Here is my code

**Item class**

```
package com.example.owner.newstock;

import com.parse.ParseClassName;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

@ParseClassName("Item")
public class Item extends ParseObject {
    public int id;
    public String item_name;
    public String item_desc;
    public String item_qty;

    public Item(){}
    public Item(int id, String item_name, String item_desc, String item_qty) {
        super();
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc = item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public Item(String item_name, String item_desc, String item_qty){
        this.item_name = item_name;
        this.item_desc=item_desc;
        this.item_qty = item_qty;
    }

    public int getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(int id){
        this.id= id;
    }
    public String getItem_name(){
        return getString(item_name);
    }

    public void setItem_name(String item_name)
    {
        put("item_name", item_name);
    }

    public String getItem_desc()
    {
        return getString(item_desc);
    }
    public  void setItem_desc(String item_desc)
    {
        put("item_desc", item_desc);
    }
    public String getItem_qty()
    {
        return getString (item_qty);
    }
    public void setItem_qty(String item_qty){
        put("item_qty", item_qty);
    }
}
```

**code of parse in main activity**

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Item.class);
Parse.initialize(this, "Kw0dyUgLoqv24QdLE30mvFBVclEzLHRGtR2hQVHA", "5BWc3bAd60EgqU0sFIj31mMYYg7OIX9WKgC0a6oP");
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
```

**code to save the objects**

```
Item i = new Item();
i.setItem_name(item_name);
i.setItem_desc(item_desc);
i.setItem_qty(item_qty);
i.saveInBackground();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: can we save the objects in parse without registering subclass???

Comment: I copied your code exactly, and I am able to get it to show the different columns in the data browser. Is it possible that the code that creates `i` and saves it isn't getting run? Try debugging and adding break points to ensure that the code is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than creating an item class that extends ParseObject, set up a ParseObject variable, as follows:

```
ParseObject item = new ParseObject("Item");
```

Then put data in as follows:

```
item.put("quantity", yourQuantityVariable);
item.put("description", yourDescriptionVariable);
item.put("name", yourNameVariable);
```

To save:

```
item.saveInBackground();
```

To retrieve data, make use of querying and the getDataType() methods. Specified on https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects and https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries

Comment: This is more of an answer to his/her comment rather than an answer to the given question.